# Losing my mind over simple conversion of common Acceleration PSD-Units: g²/Hz to (m/s²)²/Hz

Tags: fft, power-spectral-density

Because it causes confusion within my team I wanted to create a simple overview on how to convert from one PSD Unit to another. I know it is really simple but I've obsessed over it for a few hours. I feel like I'm blind to simple mistakes at this point. Would you agree with what I compiled in that overview?

## Conversion of PSD-Units $\frac{\left(\frac{m}{s^2}\right)^2}{Hz} \leftrightarrow\frac{g^2}{Hz}$

\begin{align}
&\frac{(\frac{m}{s^2})^2}{Hz} \tag{I}\\
&\frac{g^2}{Hz} \tag{II}\\
\frac{m}{s^2} &\tilde{} \frac{g}{10}\\
\mbox{In (I) : } 1\frac{(\frac{m}{s^2})^2}{Hz}  &= \frac{(\frac{g}{10})^2}{Hz} = \frac{\frac{g^2}{10^2}}{Hz} = \frac{1}{10^2} \frac{g^2}{Hz}\\
\mbox{In (II) : } 1\frac{g^2}{Hz}  &= \frac{(10\frac{m}{s^2})^2}{Hz} = 10^2 \frac{(\frac{m}{s^2})^2}{Hz}\\
\end{align}

Comment: you forgot the ² in your 1(m/s²) in the first formula bottom left. I'm not really sure where the signal processing problem is here, though: this all feels like asking how to apply the rules for exponentiation to products in parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, it's true what you are saying. But I think everyone has encountered a rather simple problem while working on a signal processing problem because it can get complicated fast - especially in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: in this context we consider $g$ to be a unit of acceleration and not a unit of mass (1 gram). It's bad practice to use the same symbol for different units, but in this case its unfortunately common practice).

A physical quantity always contains two parts: a number and a unit and the quantity is the product of both. For any any equation the product of both parts needs to be the same on both sides of the equation. We can write

$$ 1 g \approx 10 \frac{m}{s^2} \tag{1}$$
$$ 1 \frac{m}{s^2} \approx \frac{1}{10} g \tag{2} $$

You can do math with units just as you can with other numbers or variables. If we have a quantity of say $I_1 = 400\frac{(m/s^2)^2}{Hz} $ we use equation (2) replace $m/s^2$ with $1/10 \cdot g$. We get

$$ I_1 = 400 \frac{(m/s^2)^2}{Hz} =  400 \frac{(1/10 \cdot g)^2}{Hz} = 400 \frac{1}{100} \frac{g^2}{Hz} = 4 \frac{g^2}{Hz} \tag{3} $$

Note that $400 \frac{(m/s^2)^2}{Hz}$ and $4 \frac{g^2}{Hz}$ are the SAME physical quantity. The numbers are different, the units are different, but the product is the same.

This method works for all type of unit conversions. In your case its simple: to convert from $\frac{(m/s^2)}{Hz}$ to $\frac{g}{Hz}$ divide the number of quantity by 100. Multiply by 100 for the opposite conversion.

Comment: Thank you Hilmar!

Comment: For those struggling with the equation $1 g \approx 10 \frac{m}{s^2}$ like I did, here $g$ is the gravitational constant for Earth (small-g) not grams. :-D

Comment: @PeterK.: good catch! To be nit picky: in this context $g$ is not the gravitational constant itself but it's unit of acceleration. The unit is chosen so that earth's gravity becomes $1g$.

Comment: @Hilmar D'oh! I see. Thanks for the clarification.  I found the OP confusing and it took me a while to get there. :-)